# Returning data after query - Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm not sure why this is not working

js - it alerts the width, sends it to the controller but it won't alert 'done'.

Network -> Preview (inspect element Chrome)
`content: "<ul><li>50</li></ul>"`
`status: "ok"`

```
$("#submit").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
    var width = $('#value').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://domain.com/index.php/welcome/get_items",
        data: {
            width: width
        }
    }).done(function(data) {
        $('div#cont').text(data);
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('Failed!')
    });

});
```

controller

```
public function get_items()
{
        $this->load->model('home_model');

            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('width', 'Width', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
            $width = $_GET['width'];

var_dump($width);
        $one_exp = $this->home_model->one_exp($width);
var_dump($one_exp);
        if($one_exp != false){
                //$html = '<ul>';
                foreach($one_exp as $exp) {
                        $html = $exp->width;
                }
                //$html .= '</ul>';
                $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $html);
                //header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($result);
                exit();
        }else{
                $result = array('status' => 'no', 'content' => 'nothing here');
                //header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($result);
                exit();
        }

}
```

home_model

```
function one_exp($width) {
       $query_str = "SELECT * FROM files WHERE width=?";
       $query = $this->db->query($query_str, array($width));

    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $item) {
            $data[] = $item;
        }
            return $data;
    } else {
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you using? If you're using a later version, your syntax may simply not be working. You may also be encountering an [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) failure.

That said, try using jQuery 1.9.X or higher, and use the more verbose `$.ajax` method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#click").click(function () {
        var width = $('#width').val();
        alert(width);
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://mywebsite.com/index.php/welcome/get_items",
            data: {
                width: width
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('Failed!')
        });

    });
});
```

See it in action here, and also the cross-origin failure is visible in the console log: http://jsfiddle.net/remus/LcTe4/

Don't forget to remove the `echo` indicated in Ashok's answer, and you're best to add the json content type:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
` i m using the latest jquery

Comment: OK - try using the $.ajax method and see if you can get it to work.

Comment: I did ... and it does. But if I `alert(data.content)` I get undefined. I want to do something like this `$('div#container').text(data.content)`

Comment: data is the content in this case. try `$('div#container').text(data);`. Alternatively, since you're working with JSON, you may want to do `JSON.parse(data)` and then actually work with it as a javascript object.

Comment: Also, see Ashok's answer below as well -- if your controller is outputting formatted JSON (which, by the way, you should add `header('Content-type: application/json');` too), it's not going to be valid JSON.

Comment: where does `header('Content-type: application/json');` go? I just updated my question with what I have now. Take a look please.

Comment: I edited the ^ answer too, see the bit about header and removing the `echo`

Comment: No, add it directly before the JSON echo -- see my example in the answer body.

Comment: I m sorry, but it's not working. Can you please take a look at my question? I've added my latest code. Everything is fine, but I can't get that ajax script to add the content in the div. Yesterday I was at work and thought it worked ... but I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you provide the actual domain/url? impossible to properly troubleshoot without all the information.

Answer (score 2):

in your contoller remove echo

```
 public function get_items()
    {
    $this->load->model('home_model');

    $width = $this->input->post('width');

    $one_exp = $this->home_model->one_exp();

    if ($one_exp != NULL)
    {
           $html = '<ul>'; //remove echo
            foreach($one_exp as $exp)
            {
                    $html .= '<li>';
                    $html .= $exp->width;
                    $html .= '</li>';
            }
            $html .= '</ul>';
            $result = array('status' => 'ok', 'content' => $html);
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit();
    }
    else
    {
            $result = array('status' => 'no', 'content' => 'nothing here');
            echo json_encode($result);
            exit();
    }

}
```